# Which applications support the new scroll bars?

Tags: overlay-scrollbars

Will all programs in Natty have the new cool scroll bars once the final version comes out?

Answer (score 2):

Overlay scrollbars are supported in the following toolkits:

- GTK
- Qt

Work is currently ongoing for:

- XUL (Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

No, not all applications support these new scrollbars as yet (for example firefox does not). Possibly in 11.10 most of them will.